# Suppose the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is $R>0$. Prove $\forall M>\frac{1}{R}, \exists C>0, \forall n\geq0, |a_n|\leq CM^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Suppose the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is $R>0$. Prove that $\forall M>\frac{1}{R}, \exists C>0, \forall n\geq0, |a_n|\leq CM^n$.

I have just learned the concept of power series. I have tried to use contradiction to prove the proposition. Suppose otherwise, then $\exists M_0>\frac{1}{R}, \forall C>0, \exists n_0\geq 0, s.t. |a_{n_0}|\geq CM^n$, but I have no idea how to go on. (for a single $n_0$, it seems have little connection with the whole series)

The problem seems rather simple and depends only on basic logic. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M> \frac{1}{R}$. Then $\frac{1}{M} < R$, so the series
$$\sum a_n \left(\frac{1}{M}\right)^n$$

converges absolutely. In particular, $\frac{|a_n|}{M^n}$ must tend to $0$. So it is bounded, so there exists $C>0$ such that
$$\frac{|a_n|}{M^n} \leq C$$

and you are done.